# Software for automated data evaluation and export

Tags: gratis, open-source, data-analysis, data

We are searching for a (free/open source) software that does the following:

1. Take raw data from file (csv and tdms, up to several 100MB
   uncompressed)
2. Filter outliers (based on thresholds)
3. Calculate
   statistics (mean, max, min, Std.dev.)
4. Plot data (time resolved x-y-data)
5. Export a (printable, signable) pdf report including plots, table on statistics and meta data (which files were read in, date of evaluation)

Bonus would be if a developer could prepare the workflow and the technician only needs to specify the input data / folder and ends up with a printable pdf for review and signature.

Right now we are using python scripts that perform these tasks. Scripts are compiled to exe and can be executed using the data input path as a CLI argument. But at some point this is getting hard to maintain.

I already had a look at KNIME and liked how a workflow can be defined and visualised at the same time. Unfortunately I did not find a way to get a prompt for a directory input and KNIME cannot read tdms files (although we could convert tdms to xlsx or csv before using KNIME).